# Добавить метку [установка-библиотеки]

Tags: предложение, добавление-меток

Иногда появляются вопросы, связаные с установкой и/или компиляцией какой-то бибилиотеки. Однако, мне не хотелось бы их видеть (и я так подозреваю, что не только мне), по той причине, что это не сильно связано с программированием. Поэтому предлагаю добавить для таких вопросов метку [установка-библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8), чтобы его можно было добавить в игнор.

Примеры вопросов:

- [Как установить библиотеку Vreen в Qt?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663067/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-vreen-%d0%b2-qt)
- [Как установить gspread на mac os x?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657835/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-gspread-%d0%bd%d0%b0-mac-os-x/657844)

P.S: Возможно просто [установка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0) или [настройка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0) будет лучше(это взято из комментария снизу).

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры таких вопросов. По мне так, установка библиотек, необходимых для разработки, очень сильно связана с программированием. К тому же, наличие метки вовсе не гарантирует, что ТС будет её ставить. Куда проще оперировать избранными метками для выделения интересующих вопросов, чем подавлять видимость игнорируемых. Тем более, что при установке игнорируемой метки вопрос не пропадает вовсе из списка, а лишь затемняется.

Comment: @alexolut `при установке игнорируемой метки вопрос не пропадает вовсе из списка, а лишь затемняется.` - и это, кстати, очень печально.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на самом деле, в настройках профиля можно выбрать вариант и с удалением вместо затемнения.

Comment: Вряд ли, задающие вопросы будут активно пользоваться этой меткой, хотя сами по себе метки типа `установка` (не важно библиотек или чего-то другого), `настройка` и т.п. были бы полезны.

Answer (score 5):

Считаю, что такая метка не нужна, потому что:

- На неё никто не подпишется. Экспертов по абстрактной установке библиотек в вакууме нет. Есть опытные разработчики и администраторы, которые разбираются в установке библиотек/пакетов/зависимостей **с помощью конкретных инструментов**. Они подписаны на метки своих языков, экосистем и инструментов.
- Наверняка авторы вопросов нечасто будут её ставить.

  - Во-первых, потому что термин «установка библиотеки» очень специфичен. [apt-get](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apt-get), [yum](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yum) и [homebrew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) устанавливают *пакеты*, [maven](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) управляет *зависимостями*. Разработчик на Ruby наверняка не думает об «установке библиотеки» — он ставит [gems](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gems). В мире фронтенда вообще никаких библиотек — сплошные *фреймворки*.
  - Во-вторых, никто не будет ставить на свой вопрос специальную метку, благодаря которой этот вопрос кто-то сможет проигнорировать. Смысл меток-то наоборот в том, чтобы привлечь внимание экспертов.
- Такая метка не улучшит категоризацию вопроса. Например, во всех этих примерах область вопроса понятна и без метки [установка-библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8):

  - [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [pip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip) – ясно, вопрос про установку питоновых пакетов через pip.
  - [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [maven](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) – этот вопрос касается сборки Java-проекта с помощью Maven.
  - [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [nuget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuget) – что-то про установку пакетов с помощью NuGet.

Вопрос про установку библиотеки лучше отмечать:

- меткой инструмента для установки (pip, gem, nuget, и тому подобные),
- если компиляция из исходников, то меткой языка или этой самой библиотеки.

Аналогично, вопрос про использование языка отмечается меткой этого языка. Никто же не пишет [программирование-на-haskell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-haskell).

Comment: Метка библиотеки не говорит от том что именно происходит с библиотекой. То есть тег "sqlalchemy" может указывать либо на проблему с пониманием работы библиотеки, либо на проблему с её установкой. Если бы писали теги: "sqlalchemy" и "установка-библиотеки" то такой двухзначности меток не было бы.

Comment: @AndrioSkur вы можете себе представить эксперта по установке библиотек? Я не могу.

Comment: Причем тут "эксперт по установке библиотек"?

Comment: @AndrioSkur метки в первую очередь созданы для классификации вопросов, чтобы можно было сделать по ним подходящую выборку. Ваше желание - использовать метку исключительно для игнора. Поэтому и возникает логичный вопрос: кто будет целевой аудиторией для такой метки, т.е. кто добавит её в "избранное"?

Comment: В чем проблема использовать комбинацию типа [tag:sqlalchemy] , [tag:установка-библиотеки] для поиска решений возможных проблем при установке?

Comment: @AndrioSkur в том, что никто не будет ставить на свой вопрос специальную метку, благодаря которой этот вопрос кто-то сможет проигнорировать. Смысл меток-то наоборот в том, чтобы привлечь внимание экспертов. Да и сам термин «установка библиотеки» очень специфичен. `apt`, `yum` и `brew` устанавливают пакеты, Maven – управляет зависимостями. Разработчик на Ruby наверняка не думает об «установке библиотеки» — он ставит gem'ы с помощью `gem install`.

Comment: ну можно использовать как предложил https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp ,  вместо [tag:установка-библиотеки] юзать [tag:установка]

Comment: @AndrioSkur по-прежнему нет мотивации её использовать для тех, кто задаёт вопросы.

Comment: Почему нет? Вдруг кто-то наоборот очень хочет решать вопросы с установкой, но не может их найти по нормальному. Тег ему поможет. Следовательно скорость решения вопросов возрастет

Comment: @AndrioSkur такой человек подпишется на nuget, maven, gems, npm, pip и остальные метки менеджеров зависимостей.

Comment: @AndrioSkur к слову, а почему для вас так важно **вообще не видеть** вопросов про установку чего-либо?

Comment: Кокретно мне они сильно надоели. Особенно тем что люди не хотят утруждать себя пользоваться поиском и доками по установке

Comment: "такой человек подпишется на ..." -- совершенно не обязательно. Например, я не вообще не подписан ни на одну метку, но просматривая список вопросов на главной странице на метки к вопросам все же смотрю. Поэтому и приветствую появление  подобных меток (хотя они и относятся к так ненавистным "сообществу" *мета-меткам*)